# Envio de e-mails em massa

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Preciso enviar e-mails em massa com PHP, como eu posso fazer isso sem ter que esperar o PHP terminar de enviar os emails para somente depois recarregar a página?

Por exemplo, tenho que enviar 100 e-mails, mas quero continuar navegando no meu site enquanto ele continua enviado, queria colocar a tarefa como se fosse em segundo plano, é possível? Como eu procedo?

Estou usando Codeigniter.

Comment: Acredito que tenha que fazer um `exec` com `&` para rodar em segundo plano, como no shell script http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/to-run-php-code-in

Comment: Você vai precisar de algum worker ou sistema de queue para o codeigniter. Não conheço nenhum já integrado ao codeigniter, acho que terá que pesquisar um pouco.

Comment: @user13840 , eu resolvi isso ao executar arquivo php como cron. (Isso porque eu usava o linux), então eu tinha uma rotina que era executada automaticamente, sem "comer" processo na frente do usuário.